# Can doc2vec be used if my text data is incrementally increasing?

Tags: twitter, text, gensim, word2vec

I am new to Doc2vec use. In case I could get some advice before I start on it, it will save a LOT of time.
My data is an stream of text data (such as tweets) continuously coming in time. For clustering these tweets, I was thinking of using doc2vec to reduce the text content into a fixed size vector and use that to compare between documents. 
So in this case, the text data is getting accumulated over time, can this be still used with Doc2Vec, I may have to learn the model again and again (may be!) or could I use some large corpus such as Wikipedia or a large newscorpus to train the Doc2Vec model.

Any suggestions will help!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gensim Doc2Vec class does *not* support adjusting the model with new documents, but it *can* 'infer' and report a vector for new documents, based on the model learned from an earlier bulk training.

So, you can use that new inferred vector to compare the new document to older ones, or feed it to a trained classifier, etc.

If new documents continue to arrive, and especially if the balance of topics/meaning in your documents drifts over time, you would likely at some point want to discard a model based on older data, and create a new model based on your larger (or more recent) data.

(Note that vectors from the old model and new model *won't* be directly comparable. Training sessions involve a lot of randomness, and the meanings of dimensions/directions in any one model are somewhat arbitrary. It's the relative positions of vectors, from within the same model, that has some interpretive power.)

Comment: thanks you very much for the explanation!! It helps greatly. Do you have any sample working code for doc2vec?

Comment: The gensim docs/notebooks directory includes a demo doc2vec notebook that partially reproduces a sentiment-analysis experiment in the original Paragraph Vectors paper.